# Struggling to mock custom react hook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with where I'm going wrong here...

Trying to mock a custom hook but jest/enzyme is not recording any calls to the function.

My test:

```
const mockHandleEditProtection = jest.fn();
const mockUseEditProtection = jest.fn(() => [null, mockHandleEditProtection]);

jest.mock('../../common/useEditProtection', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => mockUseEditProtection,
}));

describe('my test', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<AComponent proposal={mockProposalDataWithEnrichedValues}/>)
  it('should call useEditProtection with proposal object', () => {
      expect(mockUseEditProtection).toBeCalledWith(mockProposalDataWithEnrichedValues);
  });

  it('should call edit protection when edit button is clicked', () => {
    wrapper.find(TableCell).at(4).find(Button).at(0).simulate('click');
    expect(mockHandleEditProtection).toBeCalled();
  });
})
```

A basic example of how the hook is used in a component...

```
const AComponent = ({proposal}) => {
    const [EditWarning, editProtection] = useEditProtection(proposal);
    return <div>
        {EditWarning}
        <button onClick={editProtection}>Edit</button>
    </div>
};
```

I am very confused as to why it isn't working so any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked that (1) the mock proposal object is actually delivered to the AComponent? and (2) set the hook explicitly to see whether it registers then in the spied mock function?

Comment: @keremistan I have, the other tests that check values from the mock proposal object pass (and fail when they should), and I added a console.log to AComponent to see what the hook was resolving as and it shows the mock object but the calls arent being registered :(

Comment: What did you get and what do you expect?